# subtract a cell when it has a number in it from a fixed numbered cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

We are doing a fun 'biggest loser' weight loss at work and I am tasked with recording the numbers.

I have recorded the initial weigh-in (B3). from C3 to the last weigh-in N3, weights are going to be recorded. I need O3 to calculate the weight loss/difference between B3 initial weigh-in and the most current/last weekly weigh-in.

Example:

```
B3=200  C3=194 ........... O3 needs to = 6
B3=200  C3=194  D3=192.... O3 needs to = 8
```

Comment: Do you need to compare to rightmost cell with value, or to smallest cell?

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Comment: i need to compare with most recent (date) cell, so it will go in order. with B3 being the initial weight in, C3 will be subtracted from it, then the next week, D3 will be subtracted from B3, then the next week E3 will be subtracted from B3.. and so on.

using Microsoft Excel 2007

Answer (score 3):

Set O3 to the formula: `=B3 - LOOKUP(2,1/(C3:N3<>""),C3:N3)`.

To extend the formula to the cells below, drag the right-bottom
corner of O3 downward:

[image]

Comment: THANK you!! that did it. much appreciated.

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted (the V icon).